# How to write a trivial on update rule on a view which just forwards the given update to the table represented by the view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I got table a

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   id    SERIAL,
   name  character varying NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

a view

```
CREATE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT id,name
FROM test;
```

and just want to forward a given update queue to the actual table behind the view

```
CREATE RULE TEST_VIEW_UPDATE
AS ON UPDATE TO TEST_VIEW
DO INSTEAD UPDATE TEST;
```

But this approach results in an error as the SET statement is probably missing. How can I do this correctly in the most generic (therefore no limitation on what is actually updated) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do it like this, you have to write [actual command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-update.html):

```
CREATE RULE TEST_VIEW_UPDATE
AS ON UPDATE TO TEST_VIEW
DO INSTEAD UPDATE TEST set name = NEW.name, col1 = NEW.col1 where id = NEW.id;
```

It's also possible to do what you want with triggers - check [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-triggers.html) and [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) links.

Comment: but how do I know which parameters are passed by NEW as the user might only want to update id?

e.g. `UPDATE TEST_VIEW SET id = 1000 WHERE name='bob'`

Comment: so you can write `UPDATE TEST set name = NEW.name, col1 = NEW.col1 where id = NEW.id` - update all fields which can be updated. If user updates only name, then NEW.col1 will be the same as in table, and you just update it on same value

Answer (score 3):

On PostgreSQL 9.3 this will work automatically and without changes. PostgreSQL will create simple views as updateable by default.

In prior versions, specify all columns in the `UPDATE`. There's no wildcard.

If you're on 9.1 or above (which you should always mention in every question - `select version()`) you should use an `INSTEAD OF` view trigger rather than a rule.

Comment: but how to you then prevent user from being able to update such a view - maybe they should not have the right to do so

Comment: @Sim Don't grant them `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` rights, or use a `SECURITY BARRIER` view. The SQL standard requires simple views to be updatable, PostgreSQL just hadn't implemented that before.